# What kind of API should I use to elevate user privilege to super-user in a Mac OS X?

Tags: api, macos, dialog, sudo

I want to elevate my app's privilege to super-user.
Installer app supports this by displaying [this dialog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mac_OS_X_Authenticate.png).
How can I show this dialog to elevate privilege?

PS.
I'm making a kind of packet sniffer application on Mac OS X. I'm using pcap lib. (which is part of tcpdump)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Reference/authorization_ref/Reference/reference.html) with `kAuthorizationRightExecute`

See [BetterAuthorizationSample](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/BetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004207)

As a general rule, you should not run GUI applications as root.  You should make a command line tool that you can run as root, and control it from your user space GUI application.

Comment: Why should I avoid executing GUI part as root?

Comment: @Eonil: Because [privilege separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_separation) is a good idea.